# if x['column 1] = y['column 1'] then replace that value with value in y['column 2'] in python or R

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data set that is updated daily but the system where I'm getting the data from alters some of the values. I need to correct those values in the master data so it matches other reports. I identified those values and created a data frame with the correct values in another column. I would just like to replace the 50 names with the corrected name in *Python*.

if `x['column 1] == y['column 1']` then replace that value with value in `y['column 2']`

Answer (score 0):

```
x.loc[x['column 1']==y['column 1'], 'column 1'] = y['column 2']
```

Comment: 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' . I think its because their different lengths. How would you do something like if x[column 1] is in y[column 1] then replace with y[column 2]

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`

```
y['new_column'] = np.where(x['column 1'] == y['column 1'],y['column 2'],The condition that u want whenever the if is not sastify)
```

Comment: 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects' . I think its because their different lengths. How would you do something like if x[column 1] is in y[column 1] then replace with y[column 2]